# Python 3.7 "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: host:port

Tags: python

I am working behind a firewall.

I realized I could use

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org # package name
```

to install packages but I couldn't install the `cvxpy` library this way. I then downloaded and tried to install the wheel but I didn't manage either, always getting an `EnvironmentError`.

While I was trying to find out why on SO, I came across a post suggesting to set a host:port as a global variable to avoid the issue. I followed the advice but it didn't solve my issue and now I get a host:port error whatever library I try to download.

Is there a way to cancel the global variable or reset the host:port to the default ?

Comment: What is your operating system? How did you set your `host:port` global variable?

Comment: I am on Windows 7. I set host:port with a numeric value as suggested in a post. Unfortunately I can't find that SO post anymore.

Comment: well, even if you can't find the original SO post, you can still tell us what you have done, right?

Comment: It was a week ago. The post suggested creating a global variable that assigned a numeric value to the port to allow the user to install libraries behind a firewall. Is it possible to reset the configuration ? I tried to reinstall Python to no avail.

Comment: How can SO users suggest any solution if you cannot articulate what you have done to your system and settings? `global variable` is so vague it can mean an environment variable, magic value in registry or something else in your python scripts. At the least, can you show the error stacktrace of the `EnvironmentError`, if any?

Comment: Unfortunately the traceback library is not installed and I cannot install it now. Is there a way to "reset" Python ? Reinstalling it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199501/discussion-between-statarb-and-anthony-kong).