# Issues downloading Python 3.7.4 libraries after setting a global variable

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

I am working with Python 3.7.4 64-bit behind a corporate firewall.

I have had issues downloading libraries and eventually I realized I could use

```sh
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package-name>
```

I still had issues downloading cvxpy so I followed the advice of this post: [Error when trying to setup Python pip installation behind corporate firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813278/error-when-trying-to-setup-python-pip-installation-behind-corporate-firewall)

and I set

```sh
pip config --global set global.proxy "http://user:pass@host:port"
```

which set

```sh
[global]
proxy = http://user:pass@host:port
```

Since I set the global proxy I was never able to download any library again, I'm always getting the error code: "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: host:port"

I tried to uninstall Python numerous times, deleting the registry and reinstalling, but every time I try to install a library I always get the same error message.

EDIT: I asked a related question two days ago but I was not able to specify what global variable was creating issues with downloading libraries. 
Luckily I found the post with the function I typed. I hope with this new information someone will be able to help me.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.7 "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: host:port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951821/python-3-7-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-failed-to-par)

Comment: Hi Neitsa, in the previous post I didn't specify what global function I set. This post is more detailed and I hope I can find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Did you actually write "host:port"? or are you just hiding it from the question?. It needs to be an actual proxy address like myproxy:3001

Comment: Hi Ron, I just tried to do what the user phd suggested in his answer, so I didn't assign a value. I didn't hide anything from the question.

Comment: You need to replace `host:port` with the _actual_ values based on your company's network.

Comment: Hi Gino, I looked up the ip and the port and if I try to install a library I will now get the WinError 10061: Retrying after connection broken by "ProxyError". Is there a way to restore the original pip settings to get over this issue ?

Comment: You mean `pip config --global unset global.proxy`?

Comment: Hi Gino, this really helped. Thank you!